# Sources for listings of alternative forms of common words

Tags: vocabulary, book

Do you know any good sources for listings of alternative forms of common words.
For example most websites, books and tables only show "meo" for the Ablative of "meus", but there are better sources like [THIS ONE](https://www.navigium.de/latein-woerterbuch/details?vokid=RRLX-XtH&form=meus&wb=gross&formen=AdjektivForm(NOM,SG,m,POS)#markiert) which include rare forms like "meopte".

I would like to include those rare forms in my database for an application so I would appreciate information about good sources for those kind of form tables.
Thanks!

Comment: I should note that it's not a true alternate form. It's used only by the comic playwrights, and Festus says it's equivalent to *meo ipso*. Are you looking for every single difference, then? Like illum + est = illumst, too? Or only true alternate forms, like *deum* being a poetical form of *deorum*?

Comment: @cmw First of all I'm looking for something like the second example you mentioned.

Comment: I would expect these things to appear in standard textbooks like Wheelock's or maybe somewhere in Allen and Greenough's, you might want to start there. Also, as was said before, your example *meopte* was not an alternative form, but a sort of compound form. You could have caught this by looking it up in a dictionary. You could try Logeion by the University of Chicago: https://logeion.uchicago.edu/meopte